# Application Error: JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: heroku

My Heroku app simply doesn't load when deployed (works fine locally). I'm only using a free dyno to build it, but reluctant to upgrade if I don't know that upgrading will fix it or even what tier to upgrade to.

The only thing I could find while googling says to contact their support if you get this error.. but I cant even ask them a question until upgrading. Again, reluctant to upgrade just to ask this and be told I need some top level plan.

Is there anyway I can diagnose this error myself?

```
 FATAL ERROR: MarkCompactCollector: young object promotion failed Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Comment: How much RAM do you expect to be used by your app? As per devcenter (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types) performance dynos has more ram then standard

Comment: I expect it's using VERY little ram. But of course I have no monitoring available on the free account so can't 100% tell. [edit] Also the slug size is well within limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'm a newb, so I don't fully understand why this is the problem but I'm sure I've found it. I'll put this up in case anyone else stumbles upon this thread in the future.

Locally when I run `npm start` I was shocked to see it hitting over 1GB of RAM used (viewable on task manager, windows). Then it stays roughly the same when the app is loaded and being used on `localhost`, until I close the process (obviously).

If I `npm run build` it still hits 1GB RAM, but closes when finished. Then to launch the app I `serve -s build` (`npm install -g serve` if you need it) and it launches the process using about 28MB RAM.

TLDR `npm start` seems to hog a ton of memory that it only really needed during the build process.